# Bind keeps alive after destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problems when destroying a window that has a bind to an external widget.

For example, I have one root window, and many different subwindows (in the code is the same one to make it simple).

When I open a subwindow from the root. 
It creates a window and binds to a signal from the root window. 
All the subwindows will bind to this same signal but to a different callbacks (one for each subwindow).

Then when I destroy this subwindow (click X in the top corner) the bind still alive, this means the subwindow still alive.

The question is:
How do I destroy the subwindow with its bind, leaving the other callbacks alive?

In the subwindow _destroy method, I have tried

```
root.unbind("<<EverybodyDoSomething>>", self.bind1)
```

but I get an error

> TclError: can't delete Tcl command

And if I use

```
root.unbind("<<EverybodyDoSomething>>")
```

All the callbacks assosiated with the signal get unbinded.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
i_window = 0

def generate_dosomething_signal():
    root.event_generate('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>', when = 'tail')

def subwindow():
    SubWindow()

class SubWindow(Tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        global i_window
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.i = str(i_window)
        i_window += 1
        l = Tk.Label(master=self, text='This is s Sub Window %s!!!!'%self.i)
        l.pack()
        self.bind1 = root.bind('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>', 
                               self.callback_from_sub_window, '+')

        self.bind('<Destroy>', self._destroy)

    def _destroy(self, *args):
#        root.unbind('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>', self.bind1)
#        root.unbind('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>')
        pass

    def callback_from_sub_window(self, *args):
        print 'callback from Sub Window ' + self.i

bStartWindow = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Start Sub Window', command=subwindow)
bStartWindow.pack()

bDoSomethingEverywhere = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Do something everywhere', 
                                   command = generate_dosomething_signal)
bDoSomethingEverywhere.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you say isn't the normal behavior of Tkinter. Normally when you destroy a widget, all of its children widgets get destroyed too. When they get destroyed, their bindings go with them.

Most likely, the root of your problem lies in the fact you are creating more than one instance of the root widget. You simply cannot do this. A Tkinter application must have exactly one instance of `Tk`, and exactly one instance of a running `mainloop`.

If you want more than one top level window, create instances of [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) for your second and subsequent windows.

Also, you should not be using `bind(...,"+")` to accomplish this task. As you've discovered, there is no way to remove such a binding. You can completely remove all bindings to `<<EverybodyDoSomething>>`, but you can't remove only one part that was added with `bind(..."+")`.

What you need to do instead is have a single binding that calls a single function. This function can then iterate over a list of toplevel windows, sending the event to each window. You can simply skip any windows that no longer exist. You can either use introspection to get a list of toplevel windows, or you can manually maintain this list by appending a window reference each time your code creates one.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know about Toplevel (new to Tkinter), but after changingin Tk for Toplevel, the problem persist. After creating one or more subwindows, if I close them, the "do something button" shouldn't do anything but it still calls the callbacks from the destroyed subwindows.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I want is the subwindows and their callbacks to be destroyed, not the root window.

Comment: @fariza: I've updated my answer. Short answer: you can't remove a binding the way you're doing it. You'll need to change your architecture.

Comment: Ok, I get the problem, but why the unbind does not work with the funcid returned by the bind?

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you want:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
i_window = 0

def generate_dosomething_signal():
    global root
    root.event_generate('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>', when = 'tail')

def subwindow():
    global root
    SubWindow(root)

class SubWindow():
    def __init__(self, root):
        global i_window
        self.root = root

        self.subwindow = Tk.Toplevel()
        self.i = str(i_window)
        self.destroyed = False
        i_window += 1
        l = Tk.Label(master=self.subwindow, text='This is s Sub Window %s!!!!'%self.i)
        l.pack()
        self.bind1 = self.root.bind('<<EverybodyDoSomething>>', 
                               self.callback_from_sub_window, '+')
        self.subwindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._destroy)
        #self.subwindow.bind('<Destroy>', self._destroy)

    def _destroy(self, *args):
        self.subwindow.destroy()
        self.destroyed = True
        print "Destroyed ", self.i


    def callback_from_sub_window(self, *args):
        if self.destroyed == False:
            print 'callback from Sub Window ' + self.i


bStartWindow = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Start Sub Window', command=subwindow)
bStartWindow.pack()

bDoSomethingEverywhere = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Do something everywhere', 
                                   command = generate_dosomething_signal)
bDoSomethingEverywhere.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Definitively, they told you, you need to create the subwindows as toplevels. Furthermore, notice that each time that a Subwindow() python object is created, it is a pointer to the root window who is bound to the < < EverybodyDoSomething > > event and then attaches as a callback the local instance of the function callback_from_sub_window(). Despite the window is destroyed (from the Tk point of view), the Subwindow() object for such a subwindow still exists, and hence its callback_from_sub_window() function. As is the root window who reacts to the event, goes and executes the "private" callback_from_sub_window() functions of each created (and/or destroyed) subwindows. Installing a self.destroyed flag into the Subwindow() class can prevent that the destroyed subwindows react as a callback.

Comment: This actually does not do what I want, it just fakes a destroy, the instance still alive, so a memory leak.